# Undefined reference to SDL_Freesurface

Tags: c, makefile, sdl

I'm having trouble when compiling my program.

First, here is **the makefile** I'm using :

```
LFLAGS = `sdl-config --cflags` `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL -lSDL_image 
CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/SDL
HFLAGS = main.h fisherman.h jdv.h
all: jdv

jdv: main.o fisherman.o jdv.o
    gcc main.o fisherman.o jdv.o $(LFLAGS) -o jdv -g -Wall
main.o: main.c $(HFLAGS)
    gcc -c main.c $(CFLAGS)
fisherman.o: fisherman.c $(HFLAGS)
    gcc  -c fisherman.c $(CFLAGS)
jdv.o: jdv.c $(HFLAGS)
    gcc -c  jdv.c $(CFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

A sample of the program :

**in main.h**

```
extern SDL_Surface * event;
extern SDL_Surface * map;
```

**in main.c**

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>
#include "main.h"

     void loadGame()
        {
             SDL_Surface * event = NULL;
            SDL_Surface * map = NULL; 
        ...
        }
```

And here is the output :

```
make
gcc main.o fisherman.o jdv.o `sdl-config --cflags` `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer  -o jdv -g -Wall
main.o: in « main »:
main.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to « event »
main.c:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to « event »
main.c:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to « map »
```

And it goes for ~ 75 errors like this on different variable. But they are all due to a global variable.

I think it is due to linking problem, but I don't know if it comes from my makefile, or I failed on making a global variable. Why is it telling me the "undefined reference" ?
Thanks.

**EDIT** : I ran sdl-config --libs -> output :

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL
```

Comment: Can you please just run `sdl-config --libs` on command prompt and paste the ourput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main.h`, you declare `event` and `map` as global variables.

In `main.c`, you define `event` and `map` as local variables inside `loadGame()`.  These hide the global variable definitions (and `gcc -Wshadow` would tell you about this).

None of the code you show defines the external variables.

Probably, you need to move the two lines shown in `loadGame()` outside of the function; that would cure the `event` and `map` missing references.

The question title mentions `SDL_FreeSurface` but the rest of the question doesn't.  I'll make a wild guess but maybe you need to link `-lSDL_image` before `-lSDL` rather than after.